# google maps in redux form

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

i'd like to use google maps for getting lat and long  using redux form. I create this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { compose, withProps, lifecycle } from 'recompose';
import { withScriptjs, withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker } from 'react-google-maps';

const MyMapComponent = compose(
    withProps({
        googleMapURL:
            'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCYSleVFeEf3RR8NlBy2_PzHECzPFFdEP0&libraries=geometry,drawing,places',
        loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
        containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
        mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    }),
    lifecycle({
        componentWillMount() {
            const refs = {};

            this.setState({
                position: null,
                onMarkerMounted: ref => {
                    refs.marker = ref;
                },

                onPositionChanged: () => {
                    const position = refs.marker.getPosition();
                    console.log(position.toString());
                },
            });
        },
    }),
    withScriptjs,
    withGoogleMap
)(props => (
    <GoogleMap defaultZoom={8} defaultCenter={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }}>
        {props.isMarkerShown && (
            <Marker
                position={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }}
                draggable={true}
                ref={props.onMarkerMounted}
                onPositionChanged={props.onPositionChanged}
            />
        )}
    </GoogleMap>
));

class MyParentComponentWrapper extends React.PureComponent {
    state = {
        isMarkerShown: false,
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <MyMapComponent isMarkerShown={true} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default MyParentComponentWrapper;
```

But it does not return any values and the does not show the lat and long in the field What should i do? it will console.log the lat and long when user drag the marker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `MyMapComponent` to return the value to `MyParentComponentWrapper` just pass a callback function as a prop. Just change the parent component to:

`<MyMapComponent isMarkerShown={true} onMakerPositionChanged={this.onMakerPositionChanged}/>`

and the map component to:

`onPositionChanged: () => {
   const position = refs.marker.getPosition();
   console.log(position.toString());
   this.props.onMakerPositionChanged(position);
},`

See working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nkvjyppzom)

Comment: hi i like to do inside the redux form ., how to do it ?

Comment: can you clarify your question? And even better, please fork the working example I posted and show how you would like to use it with redux-form.

Comment: i am using redux-form ., inside of the redux-form i have to implement the gooogle map as you shown above but i can"t able to get the value or pass the value to redux-form .,

Comment: In general, you can set a value in redux-form by calling `this.props.change(fieldName, value)` in the component which uses `redux-form` (which I don't see in your code)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/mZRjw05yp ., my simple redux from i can't able to get the value from google map to redux-form

Comment: take a look at this i implemented your map component to redux form but i can"t able to get values from in it  https://codesandbox.io/s/nkploj0nw0

Comment: You need to fire a callback from your component to the form when position is set, check working example https://codesandbox.io/s/53vlzzww74